# Can I populate a expandable listview with json data using volley?

Tags: android, json, listview

**As a novice user** , I m trying to populate an expandable listview with json data **using a volley** string request. But I cannot create a linkedhashmap to populate my headers and child. A part of my problem is described here

[I cannot return a LinkedHashMap from method and I get null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792534/i-cannot-return-a-linkedhashmap-from-method-and-i-get-null)

where I am suggested to check asynchronous and sychronous callbaks. All examples I find describe expandable listview **with async task**..

So is it possible to populate it using volley and **in what way**?

Thank you !!

Comment: AsyncTask returns a string from a url no different than a volley string request, so what's the issue?

Comment: I call my method which includes my volley request and it returns a linkedhashmap but it returns null! and because I am confused I thought that using async task it will solve that problem

Comment: You don't need AsyncTask for http requests  if you are using volley